# On creating a new android project source folder is empty

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create a new project with API level 8 the project is created with no errors but the `src` folder is empty. Please, help with my problem.....[click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcUN3.png)

Comment: What are you expecting to be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right button click on `src` folder, select New -> Java Class and start working

Comment: Thank you I started working like this....And its working fine...

Answer (score 0):

When create new project, please make sure you have check in **Create activity** like this.

[image]